# How to use Resources.resw in Class library project in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I am currently working on Windows 10 UWP. At first, I only had one project to which I added a Constants.resw file to use resources which I saved in local storage and accessed them later. Now I have created a Background Task of type *Timer* and I want to access my database in Timer Background Task project so I created a Class Library Project and added all the POJOS and Utils classes in that project. Can someone suggest whether I can add a Constants.resw in class library project and how?

Also, I want to access it using below code which I used when I had a single project(Windows 10 UWP Project)

```
ApplicationDataContainer userSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if (!userSettings.Containers.ContainsKey(Constants.DB_AVAILABLE)) //if (!checkIfDBExists().Result)
{
     //some operations
}
```

When, I try to use Constants.resw in my background tasks, I get following error

```
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Common.dll
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Common.CommonResources.Constants' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.get_Current()
at Common.CommonResources.Constants..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Common.CommonResources.Constants.get_DB_AVAILABLE()
at Common.DatabaseManager.getSQLiteConnection()
at Common.DatabaseManager.getLocationDetails()The type initializer for 'Common.CommonResources.Constants' threw an exception.
```

Comment: How are you accessing it? please post that code too

Comment: I am trying to access using above code `userSettings` one. Also, how can I access files from Class library in Background tasks. I unzipped a file when running my UWP project in local storage but when in background tasks not able to access it directly. Do I need to load each and every file differnetly for background tasks?

Comment: You are gettting error in this Constants.DB_AVAILABLE? Isnt Constants a static class? what is it?. Post that class

Comment: If it is Resourses.resw file you have to use like this App.StringResource.GetString(Constants.DB_AVAILABLE)

Comment: ok but what about files?Do I need to access them every time from storage?

Comment: You said you created it in separate Class library. Let it be there

Comment: No I am talking other file that I unzipped. And I am not able to use `App.StringResource.GetString` in class library.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110814/discussion-between-lovetocode-and-kinjan-bhavsar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add a Resources.resw file to your Class Libraries or Windows Runtime Components because resources works at app level not at project level.
This means your resources in your main app project can be "seen" and used across all your projects in your app. This is an example of how you can load resources externally:

```cs
ResourceContext resourceContext = ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse();
ResourceMap resourceMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Resources");

// Here you load the resource you need
var resourceValue = resourceMap.GetValue("resourceName", resourceContext);
```

Comment: Then how to store my constants in local settings?

Comment: In the same way you usually do, using ApplicationDataContainer.

Comment: Ok is there not a way to use it using resx or resw files as there are lots of parameters I am using in Constants.resw right now. And it's string name and value pair

Comment: Also,how to add new constants with key,value in the ResourceMap?

Comment: You can always place the resw file in your class library or winrt component and then read it as I show it before. ResouceMap it's a resource reader, so it can't write anything, it's read-only. By the way I don't know what you're trying to achieve but I'm starting to think that maybe all you need it's a serialized file or a static class of properties, that you'll eventually store in the local settings of your app. What is the point in putting them in a resource file and then copying them to local settings?

Comment: I am storing some local values using them in my local settings.

Comment: Added error that I am getting when I try to use `Constants.resw` in my `Background Task`

Comment: Hi, this solution works in some scenarios only using "Libraby Assembly Name" qualifier for SubTree, like "testdll/Resources" (testdll.dll) or if your assembly name have dot, like "testdll.abc/Resources" (testdll.abc.dll). More in http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=780#comment-7477